# Need to decode entity-encoded string with java

Tags: java, html, entity

I have XML document where one tag has value - `Außewölf`. After processing this document by Axis adapter it looks like

```
Au&#xC3
;
&#x192
;
&#xC5
;
&#xB8
;
ew&#xC3
;
&#x192
;
&#xC2
;
&#xB6
;
lf
```

Is there any way to return value representation to original?

I've tried **StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4** method but it returns:

```
AuÃƒÅ¸ewÃƒÂ¶lf
```

Comment: You have some *very* weird code page conversion issues going on here. It seems that the original XML wasn't even read in the right code page, so check that first.

Comment: Original XML is marked with "UTF-8". I guess it's a bug of Axis adapter I have to use. I can't do anything with it for a while. So I want to try to fix it with java code.